# Would the US postal service be open on election day were election day made a legal public holiday?

Tags: united-states, vote-by-mail, specific-legislation, postal-service

The [For the People Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_the_People_Act) is a voting rights bill currently under debate in the U.S. Senate.  Two of its provisions include

- expanding voting by mail, and
- making election day a national holiday.

These two provisions seem to conflict with each other.  The U.S. Postal Service is usually closed on national holidays, which in turn would interfere with the sending, processing, and delivery of mailed ballots.  If the act becomes law, will the postal service still be open (and to what extent) on election day?

---

Update: It appears that the "For the People Act" has been superceded by the "Freedom to Vote Act."  I actually started writing the question with "Freedom to Vote Act", but Wikipedia [redirects that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_to_Vote_Act) to the "For the People Act."  Thinking I made a typo, I revised the question to "For the People Act."  Turns out that (surprise!) Wikipedia is wrong.

As the two bills seem to cover the same provisions relevant to this question, I would accept an answer based on either bill.

Comment: I think it is hard to say at this point and currently only 12 states allow for a mail in ballot to be postmarked on election day. At the very least I would expect the post office to deliver ballots to counting locations on election day.

Comment: [H.R.4](https://www.congress.gov/bill/117th-congress/house-bill/4) - John R. Lewis Voting Rights Advancement Act of 2021, is the bill Democrats wanted to pass, by January 17, 2022 (today).

Comment: @RickSmith: There are two bills they want to pass.  This question is about H.R. 1.

Comment: The second bill is [S.2747](https://www.congress.gov/bill/117th-congress/senate-bill/2747) - Freedom to Vote Act. *See,* [The Democrats' two bills: the Freedom to Vote Act and the John Lewis Voting Rights Act – would set new minimum standards for early and mail-in voting, among other changes.](https://www.npr.org/2022/01/11/1071829164/biden-speech-voting-rights-filibuster-senate). The question can be about H.R.1, but that bill is not currently active.

Comment: In S.2747, see [PART 2—ELECTION DAY AS LEGAL PUBLIC HOLIDAY](https://www.congress.gov/bill/117th-congress/senate-bill/2747/text#toc-H04DD889185C94C049D084F682708BA5E).

Comment: Too hypothetical to answer. It depends entirely on exactly what the purported legislation would say.

Comment: Many comments deleted. Please don't use comments to debate the question matter. If you would like to answer, please post a real answer. If you would like to discuss, please use the chat function. Please try to limit these comments to suggesting improvements to the question.

Comment: Related question: Is the post office _required_ to be closed for federal holidays (as a category)?  Or does it just happen to be required to be closed for every federal holiday that currently exists ("closed on _these_ days")?  Or is it really up to the Postmaster General and there are no legal requirements one way or the other?  Depending on which it is, it's quite possible that they would be open despite it being a federal holiday.

Answer (score 3):

You have to [dig around a bit in the text](https://www.congress.gov/bill/117th-congress/house-bill/1/text#:%7E:text=306.%20Early%20voting.%27%27.-,Subtitle%20I%2D%2DVoting%20by%20Mail,-SEC.%201621.%20VOTING) of the bill, but it contains this requirement:

> Same-day processing.—The United States Postal
> Service shall ensure, to the maximum extent practicable, that
> ballots are processed and cleared from any postal facility or
> post office on the same day the ballots are received at such a
> facility or post office.

It would seem that, if a state allows mail-in votes on election day, then under this act, the postal service would be required to process these on the same day that they are received.

But note:

> Deadline for returning ballot.—A State may
> impose a reasonable deadline for requesting the
> absentee ballot and related voting materials from the
> appropriate State or local election official and for
> returning the ballot to the appropriate State or local
> election official.

So it would be normal for a state to require that mail-in votes are posted prior to election day.

Comment: I think ensuring that the ballot are processed is different then the post office being open. From my understanding they process mail every day of the year even if the offices themselves are not open to the public.

Comment: Yes, so you'd expect the state to set a deadline for posting prior to election day, and so ballots posted on election day will miss that deadline and so not get counted.

Comment: You would think that but 12 states allow for a ballot to be postmarked on election day. And most of those states have plenty of time for them to get delivered as long as someone isn't purposely delaying the mail